# take device snapshot programmatically in android

Tags: android, screenshot, menubar, snapshot, screen-capture

How can I take snapshot of device like this tablet has button in menu bar to take a snap shot of device screen?
[image]
the device has android 4.1.1
[image]
this same functionality is wanted to implement in my application to capture the screen snapshot.

note that:

- I don't want to use `Layout.getDrawingCache();`
- I only want to access this method as the OS uses.or a solution like this
- I do not need to root device.so please do not provide root solutions

Comment: Why not `getDrawingCache()`?

Comment: because it takes only the layout area..i want to use whole device screen area.@Nizam and dear its totally a different question @Wilhelmsen

Comment: @hamad I was a bit fast there, removed it :)

Answer (score 1):

just have a look on this https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/
i hope it usefull for you...